# Q. For c programmer , Does str="Hello" indicate string copy? what are the reason behind this?

Tags: c

```
char *str1;
str1 = "Hello";
```

In the above code, does `str1 = "Hello";` indicate string copy? what are the reasons?

Comment: No. It indicates pointer assignment.

Comment: [so] is not the place to learn language basic. You should use language tutorial/reference sites instead.

Comment: Not a string copy. In memory "Hello" is stored and corresponding memory pointer is assigned to str1.

Comment: The constant string literal `"Hello"` is a read-only array of six characters. The assignment makes `str1` point to the first element of that array. So in a way it *is* copying, but not what you probably think it's copying. What's copied is the address of the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, C language itself is not fully aware of *strings*. It only handles characters and pointers to them. What makes a C string is a convention by which an array of characters (an array is just a pointer to an allocated blob of memory) terminated by a null character `'\0'` can be handled as a string.

The only place where C is aware of strings is literal constants in code, like `"Hello"` in your example, which allocate memory containing those characters and followed by `'\0'`.

`char *` does not declare a string variable. It declares a pointer to a character.

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro